# How can I put padding between elements in a span or why doesn't css padding work in a span?

Tags: html, css

Sorry for the long title, but SO would not accept the second clause as a title.

I have a Vuejs 3 component with an input text box and a search button in an span.  I want some space between the text box and button.  Simple, right?  Not with css.  Here's the code:

```css
.headerelement {
  padding-right: 50px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<span style="padding-right: 20px; background-color: lightblue">
  <input type="text" placeholder="City?" v-model="this.$store.state.city" class="headerelement">
  <button id="search" @click="getGeocodeForLocation" style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <img src="../assets/search.svg" width="24" height="24" alt="search"/>
  </button>
</span>
```

I've added `padding-right` to the text box and `padding-left` to the left of the search button, but neither works:

[image]

The `padding-right` on the `<span...>` does work, but not for the elements inside of `<span...>`.

Is this a pathology of  or maybe some bug in Vuejs 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `margin-right` not `padding-right`. **Padding** clears an area around the content. While **margin** clears an area outside the border. You can look at it as padding, being the space inside the border, and margin being the space outside. Adding `padding-right` to your input would give it more space inside it instead of outside it. More on CSS box model [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_boxmodel.asp).

```css
.headerelement {
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: cadetblue;
}
```

```html
<span style="padding-right: 20px; background-color: lightblue">
  <input type="text" placeholder="City?" v-model="this.$store.state.city" class="headerelement">
  <button id="search" @click="getGeocodeForLocation" style="padding-left: 10px;">
    <img src="../assets/search.svg" width="24" height="24" alt="search"/>
  </button>
</span>
```

Comment: The box model link you provided illustrates this well.